# Client-Side Image Map Example - doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I tried to do easy example of Client-Side Image Map. But this wasn't succeeded.
Output at browser only:  `Clicked Item:` 
Code looks OK. But still don't work. Why?

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Client-Side Image Map Example</title>
            <script>
                function update(t) {
                    document.form1.text1.value = t;
                }
            </script>
    </head> 
        <body>
            <map name="map1">
                <area shape=rect coords="14,15,151,87" onClick="javascript:update('Servis');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='Servise department'; return true;">
                <area shape=rect coords="162, 16, 283, 85" onClick="javascript:update('Shop');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='Sales department'; return true;">
                <area shape=rect coords="294, 15, 388, 87" onClick="javascript:update('About as');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='About as'; return true;">
                <area shape=rect coords="13, 98, 79, 178" onClick="javascript:update('Email');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='Write to as'; return true;">
                <area shape=rect coords="92, 97, 223, 117" onClick="javascript:update('Goods');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='Goods & service'; return true;">
                <area shape=rect coords="235, 98, 388, 177" onClick="javascript:update('History');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='History'; return true;">
                <area shape=default onClick="javascript:update('No item selected.');"
                    onMouseOver="window.status='Please select an item.>
            </map>
            <h1>Client-Side Image Map Example</h1>
            <hr>
                The image map below uses JavaScript functions in each of its areas. Moving over
                an area will display information about it in the status line. Clicking on an area
                places the name of the area in the text field below the image map.
            <hr>
                <image src="imagemap.qif" usemap="#map1">
            <hr>
                <form name="form1">
                    <b>Clicked Item:</b>
                    <hr>
                    <input type="text" name="text1" value="Please select an item.">
                </form>
            <hr>
        </body>    
</html>
```

**Qestion:**

- How to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed your code. There were some issues:
- missing return statement for one area
- missed language annotation for script tag
- general formatting

Here is a fixed code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Map Example</title>
            <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                function update(t) {
                   document.form1.text1.value = t;
                }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <map NAME="map1">
            <area SHAPE=RECT COORDS="14,15,151,87" onClick="update('service');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Service Department'; return true;">
            <area SHAPE=RECT COORDS="162,16,283,85" onClick="update('sales');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Sales Department'; return true;">
            <area SHAPE=RECT COORDS="294,15,388,87" onClick="update('info');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Information'; return true;">
            <area SHAPE=RECT COORDS="13,98,79,178" onClick="update('email');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Email Us'; return true;">
            <area SHAPE=RECT COORDS="92,97,223,177" onClick="update('products');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Products'; return true;">
            <area SHAPE=RECT COORDS="235,98,388,177" onClick="update('our staff');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Our Staff'; return true;">
            <area SHAPE=default onClick="update('No item selected.');"
            onMouseOver="window.status='Please select an item.'; return true;">
        </map>
        <h1>Client-Side Image Map Example</h1>
        <hr>
            The image map below uses JavaScript functions in each of its areas. Moving over
            an area will display information about it in the status line. Clicking on an area
            places the name of the area in the text field below the image map.
        <hr>
            img SRC="imagemap.gif" USEMAP="#map1">
        <hr>
            <FORM NAME="form1">
                <b>Clicked Item:</b>
                <input TYPE="text" NAME="text1" VALUE="Please select an item.">
            </form>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```